# Share Google group permissions with GCP service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-workspace, google-groups

A Google group of which I'm Manager have been granted certain permissions to access certain BigQuery tables. Effectively all user in the group can access to those tables using their personal credentials.

I would like to share those permissions with a service account and access the tables using service account credentials.

Is this possible? How to configure it?

Answer (score 0):

A service account is generally used for Server to Server communication (between applications). With that in mind, a service account has associated an email address just like the ones associated to your personnel. So, you can assign roles/permissions to the service accounts using its email just like you assigned to your group.

I hope that the following steps help you in some manner:

1. [Create](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating_a_service_account) a service account.
2. Assign predefined [BigQuery roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts#granting_access_to_a_service_account_for_a_resource) (Admin, DataEditor, User, etc).
3. Download its json file which contains the credentials.
4. Use those credentials to [authenticate and authorize your application](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests).
5. To [add a specific permission](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets#controlling_access_to_a_dataset) (owner, edit or view) on a specific dataset you can use its service account email.